# block function and memory issue in object-c

Tags: ios, memory, exc-bad-access, objective-c-blocks

I want to test the block function and the value for the context. The test code is:

//xxx.h

```
@interface textObj :  NSObject 
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * num;
@end

typedef void (^ returnHandle)(NSNumber * res);

@interface BlockTest : NSObject

- (void) textBlock:(textObj *)num completionHandler:(void (^)(NSNumber * res))handler;

@end
```

//xxx.m

```
@implementation textObj
@synthesize num;

@end

@interface BlockTest (){
    returnHandle rt;
}

- (void)toggleChromeDisplay;

@end

@implementation BlockTest

- (void) dealloc{
    Block_release(rt);
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)toggleChromeDisplay
{
    NSNumber *ret = [NSNumber numberWithInt:111];
    rt(ret);
}

void (^handle)(NSNumber * res, NSError *error);


- (void) textBlock:(textObj *)g1 completionHandler:(void (^)(NSNumber * res))handler
{
    rt = Block_copy(handler);
    [self performSelector:@selector(toggleChromeDisplay) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
    return;
}

@end
```

The test sample invoke code is :

```
//first sample code...
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    test = [[BlockTest alloc]init];
    textObj * g1;
    g1 = [[textObj alloc] init];
    [g1 setNum:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10]];
    NSLog(@"main 0 g1 num=%@ count=%d", [g1 num], [g1 retainCount]);
    [test textBlock:g1 completionHandler:^(NSNumber *res) {
        NSLog(@"value=%@", [g1 num]);
        [g1 setNum:[NSNumber numberWithInt:20]];
        NSLog(@"main 1 g1 num=%@ count=%d", [g1 num], [g1 retainCount]);
    } ];
    NSLog(@"main 2 g1 num=%@ count=%d", [g1 num], [g1 retainCount]);
    [g1 release];
    NSLog(@"main 3 g1 num=%@ count=%d", [g1 num], [g1 retainCount]);  
}
```

In the block function, i can change the g1 value. It is OK.
But when I declare the g1 as the public value for the test, it will error in the block function. The g1 can not be access. **It output the EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=0x26) error**.

```
//second sample code...
@interface UIMainViewController (){
@public
    textObj * g1;
}
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    test = [[BlockTest alloc]init];
    //textObj * g1;
    g1 = [[textObj alloc] init];
    [g1 setNum:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10]];
    NSLog(@"main 0 g1 num=%@ count=%d", [g1 num], [g1 retainCount]);
    [test textBlock:g1 completionHandler:^(NSNumber *res) {
        NSLog(@"value=%@", [g1 num]);
        [g1 setNum:[NSNumber numberWithInt:20]];
        NSLog(@"main 1 g1 num=%@ count=%d", [g1 num], [g1 retainCount]);
    } ];
    NSLog(@"main 2 g1 num=%@ count=%d", [g1 num], [g1 retainCount]);
    [g1 release];
    NSLog(@"main 3 g1 num=%@ count=%d", [g1 num], [g1 retainCount]);  
}
```

I am confuse the two different sampe code, why the second test code will meet crash?

Comment: "It will error" -- and what the error is?

Comment: can not access the value g1. EXC_BAD_ACCESS error will output.

Comment: of course it does... After `[g1 release]`, g1 is deallocated, so the 2nd NSLog can't really do much to it...

Comment: But why the first test sample can work?

Comment: Because the object is only deallocated AFTER THE FIRST NSLOG AND BEFORE THE SECOND, because you call that goddamned release THERE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary problem is that, as @H2CO3 points out, you're releasing `g1` before the block is executed. The reason it works in one case and not the other is that [blocks retain any local object variables they refer to when copied](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-08-14-practical-blocks.html).

In your first example, `g1` is a variable local to the method scope, so the block retains it.

In your second example, `g1` is an ivar (effectively `self->g1`), so the block retains `self`. But you release `g1` right after you declare the block, so when the block calls `self->g1`, it gets an invalid pointer, because `g1` has been deallocated.

Comment: Thank for your help. For the ivar g1 (self->g1), the lifetime should be as same as the container self. This ivar should alloc in the init funcation and release in the dealloc function.

Comment: But for the first example, when the g1 will be really release? After the block is finished or the container self released? I want to make clear the memory thing between he first example and second example.

Comment: In the first example, g1 will be deallocated when the block is deallocated. For a callback, you should generally release the block after running it.

Answer (score 3):

retainCount is useless. Don't call it.  Not ever.

By definition, retainCount cannot return zero.  You are messaging a deallocated object which is undefined, often crashed behavior.